# How to set monitor display 90º rotation as default?

Tags: display

I have a external display monitor that I physically turn 90 degrees. Naturally, I must rotate the display 90 degrees to view the content.

Every time I unplug and plug in the monitor, I have to set the rotation back to 90 degrees.

How can I configure this to be the default? Is it possible thru mac OS? I checked the monitor's hardware display settings and it does not have the option to rotate.

**Mac OS version: 10.13.6**

**Monitor product id: Dell UP3017**

Edit:
I do not believe this is a duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut flip screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319938/keyboard-shortcut-flip-screen) -- that question is asking for a hotkey to change the setting. My goal is to set a default setting and forget about it.

Comment: can we know what monitor is it ? what macos ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I updated my question with this info

Comment: and promptly you get a up-vote from me :), now lets see if someone has done this before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut flip screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319938/keyboard-shortcut-flip-screen)

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't think so. I'm looking to assign a default setting. Not a hotkey

Comment: something like `defaults write com.apple.displays -int 90`

Comment: Will that assign 90 degrees to all displays? I also have a second external display that I **do not** want to be rotated

Comment: that was just a example, it needs to be modified for your specific display